# How to execute bind variable based sql in DB2 DB2 ZOS

Tags: oracle, db2, db2-zos

I am trying to execute one SQL, which is made up of bind variables. It's working  fine with ORACLE DB but not with DB2

Here is the sample SQL: (UPPER/UCASE it can be anything)

```
SELECT Col1 FROM tab1 WHERE Col1 = 'abc' AND (UPPER(Col1) LIKE (UPPER(:1) || '%' ESCAPE '\') ORDER BY 1
```

**Error is as follows:**

```
db2 => SELECT Col1 FROM tab1 WHERE Col1 = 'abc' AND (UPPER(Col1) LIKE (UPPE
R(:1) || '%' ESCAPE '\') ORDER BY 1
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "1" was found following "".  Expected tokens mayinclude:  "<IDENTIFIER>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I am not sure, what is the problem here. Its not prompting for input bind value.
In Oracle DB, everything is working fine.

In DB2, I used command line to execute the query. For Oracle, I used ORACLE SQL developer.

Comment: Which "command line" do you mean?  If you are using the shell command line on Windows or Linux or Unix (while connected to the remote database on z/os)  then it does not offer prompting for parameter-markers.  Oracle-SQL-Developer should be able to work with remote Db2-for-Z/Os when properly configured and licensed.

Comment: Yeah currently I am using Window cmd prompt. So your suggestion is use Oracle-SQL-Develper to connect DB2? could you please provide me if there Is any reference document to setup the connection between Oracle SQL and Db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the interactive CLP for Db2 on Microsoft Windows, while connected to a remote Db2-for-Z/OS database.

This CLP interface does not have any functionality for prompting for host-variable values in dynamic-SQL. That's why you get the error message.

You can either use an alternative interface (for example IBM Data Studio, or many other java based database front-end tools) , or continue to use Oracle-SQL-Developer to access Db2 for Z/OS.

You can configure 'Oracle SQL Developer' to use the Db2 type-4 jdbc driver (db2jcc4.jar) along with the licence file for Db2 for Z/OS ('db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar').  You will need to get the Db2 licence file from your mainframe DBA or from Passport-Advantage, or alternatively connect via a Db2-connect gateway server (in which case you won't need a separate licence file on the workstation running Oracle-SQL-Developer).

However, the degree to which each such tool understands Db2-for-Z/OS varies, so if you get issues that you cannot easily workaround, then use instead the free IBM Data Studio which works with Db2-for-Z/OS,  and Db2-for-i,  and Db2 for LUW.

Configuring SQL-Developer to access Db2 is documented widely, including on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250557/db2-database-in-oracle-sql-developer) website, and also by [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html).  So do your research, this is not programming but configuration. Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Yeah. It works for me 80%. Now I am able to see the DB2 configuration window in Oracle SQL developer. But I stuck at connection establishment, giving following error.     An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

[jcc][t4][2057][11264][3.72.24] The application server rejected establishment of the connection.
An attempt was made to access a database, "DBNAME", which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004

Vendor code -4499